# Face Recognition and Comparison Software Using Old Photos

Tags: windows, images, image-recognition, facial-recognition

Can anyone suggest a free program that will work on Windows 10 allowing me to compare two scanned pictures, one lady photographed in Victorian times with a picture of someone who may have been her (or her mother) 30 years later? Hopefully, it would offer a percentage likelihood of the photo being of the same person. I also have a photo of a lady who I believe might have been the natural mother of my grandmother. Is it possible by comparing the two photos of different people to establish a probable family connection?